# Maximizing colored vertices of a graph $G$ having less than $\chi(G)$ colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Consider a $k$-partite graph $G$ of $N$ nodes and $q$ different colors with $q < k = \chi(G)$. I would like to determine how many vertices can I color at most with these $q$ colors.

Consider the following coloring algorithm: take a maximum independent set $M_1$ of $G$ and color its vertices with the first color, than consider the maximum independent set $M_2$ of the subgraph induced by $V\setminus M_1$ and color it with the second color and so on until I run out of colors.

Will this procedure always color the largest number of vertices? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: My immediate intuition, which may be wrong, is that your "greedy" approach would not always produce the largest graph. This is because, intuitively, this "feels" to me like one of the standard NP complete problems (edge/vertex colouring etc.).

Comment: Also, I think an important implicit assumption in your question is that we're trying to optimise complexity. Otherwise, we can clearly get the maximized colouring by simply trying all possible colourings, of which there are $q^N$, and then checking each one for legality.

Comment: If I were in your position now, instead of trying to prove that your procedure is optimal, perhaps try for an hour or so to look for a minimal counterexample. A small $q$ and a graph with small $N$, with a $q$-colouring that is greater than the one achieved by the greedy algorithm specified. If this proves difficult, then maybe your algorithm is optimal, but I'd go down this path first.

Comment: @Colm: I realized from your comments that the way I asked the question in an ambiguous way. All I care about is the maximum number of vertices that I can color, rather than finding the best algorithm to do so and/or calculating its complexity. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm still unsure exactly what you're looking for. It won't be a closed form formula- because it will depend on the shape of the graph. Though you might get bounds based on the number of nodes/edges. If you're looking for an algorithm to calculate it, then why not just brute force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The algorithm that you describe (colouring maximum independent sets greedily) does not always produce an optimal colouring. In other words, if you were to set $q = k = \chi(G)$ then the answer to your question would be no. (An example is the six vertex graph formed by adding a vertex adjacent to both ends of each edge in a triangle.)

So let $H$ be a graph where the algorithm fails to produce an optimal colouring, and then add an extra vertex that is adjacent to every vertex in $H$ to obtain the graph $G$. Then let $q = \chi(G) - 1$.